# how to show only the incorrect values in the dialogue box one time only

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

I am taking input from user in the edittext. Now I want to show the desired output in the other text box, but if user inputs wrong values, a dialog box should open mentioning all the incorrect values...box is opening again and again till it detects all the incorrect values. eg-if i add three wrong values in the edit box it is opening box for 3 times.

```
   String s=editText1.getText().toString();
    String z[]=s.split("\\s");
    editText2.setText("");
    String a = "";
    String b = " Not valid";

    for(int i=0;i<z.length;i++)
    {
        int j=Integer.parseInt(z[i]);

        if(j>=65 && j<=97)
        {
            editText2.setText(editText2.getText() + "" + String.valueOf((char) j));
        }
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                a += z[i]+"\t";

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(a+b)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: because your alertDialog.show(); is in for loop

Comment: keep that out side of foor loop
prepare your message in else & call alertDialog.show(); after loop is over

Comment: @user3040153 If i keep outside of for loop and call alertDialogue.show(), it is still opening for one time even if user enters correct values

Comment: put a count like if entered value is wrong it increases & check for if coubt >0 then only show alerDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    boolean is_open_dialog=false;

    for(int i=0;i<z.length;i++)
    {
        int j=Integer.parseInt(z[i]);

        if(j>=65 && j<=97)
        {
            editText2.setText(editText2.getText() + "" + String.valueOf((char) j));
        }
        else {

            is_open_dialog = true;
            a += z[i]+"\t";

        }
    }

    if(is_open_dialog){


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(a+b)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: I think this helps you @Rohan

Comment: why boolean is highlighting in red..how to correct this error

Comment: Sorry use boolean . spelling mistake.

Comment: and what about is_dialog_open...should i make it a local variable ?

Comment: i have made just a little change i your answer...i changed the is _dialogue _open to is_open _dialogue and the problem was resolved

Comment: @RajkumarKumawat can you suggest me that what should add in the code so that values are shown in the other text box only when the user have entered only corrected values...because with this code it is showing  both the corrected values in the text box and incorrect in the dialog box..